# A cmake macro for platform dependent setting variable value

Tags: cmake, macros, cross-platform

I'm writing a utility macro in cmake for setting a variable dependent on platform. Theoretically it should be simple but I don't know why my variable isn't being set. Here's the macro:

```
macro(SetCrossPlatform name msvc_val linux_val macos_val)
#macro(SetCrossPlatform VAR name MSVC msvc_val LINUX linux_val MACOS macos_val) # alternative signature that I tried

    MESSAGE(STATUS "PLATFORM ${PLATFORM}")
    if (PLATFORM STREQUAL "windows-msvc")
        set(name ${msvc_val})
    elseif (PLATFORM STREQUAL "linux")
        set(name ${linux_val})
    elseif (PLATFORM STREQUAL "macos")
        set(name ${macos_val})
    endif ()

endmacro()
```

which is invoked like:

```
#SetCrossPlatform(VAR Variable MSVC "microsoft" LINUX "ubuntu" MACOS "apple") # try other signature
SetCrossPlatform(Variable "microsoft" "ubuntu" "apple")

message(STATUS "Variable ${Variable}")
```

This produces:

```
-- PLATFORM windows-msvc
-- Variable               # <--- Should print out "-- Variable microsoft"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the macro you need to **dereference** `name` for obtain the **value** of the parameter:

```
set(${name} ${msvc_val})
```

By current code

```
set(name ${msvc_val})
```

you just define the variable with the name "name".